# Erro em ASP.MVC "não é possível encontrar o recurso"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estou iniciando em ASP.NET e tentei criar um app de teste.

Ao executar pelo Visual Studio tenho o erro do print.

Criei um projeto padrão MVC 5, criei o controller o model e a view cada um no seu devido local.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**EDIT**

Como eu faria para acessar então considerando a estrutura do projeto de acordo com a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O IIS não serve os arquivos `.cshtml` da sua aplicação. Você acessa as páginas da sua aplicação entrando nas rotas mapeadas para ela. Você vai ver como configurar essas rotas em algum momento do seu aprendizado, mas por enquanto basta saber que por padrão elas são criadas assim:

```
nome do `controller` (sem o sufixo "controller")/nome do método no controller
```

Note que, para servir HTML, você deve ter uma `view` com o mesmo nome do método.

Portanto, se você tem um `controller` chamado "fooController" e uma `view` chamada *index*, o que você procura estará em:

```
/foo/index
```

Answer (score 1):

Você nunca acessa o arquivo da *View* diretamente.

O correto é acessar a *Action* de cada *Controller*. Por exemplo, se tenho um *Controller* chamado `ProdutosController` e uma *Action* chamada `Index`, a rota será:

```
http://localhost:53710/Produtos/Index
```

Há também rotas padrão. Elas normalmente são definidas no arquivo `RouteConfig.cs`, diretório `App_Start`.

Um projeto configurado do zero trás como padrão `HomeController` como *Controller* e `Index` como *Action*. Você pode alterar se quiser.

---

**EDIT**

Como só tem um *Controller* criado, você pode acessá-lo usando:

```
http://localhost:53710/Categorias
```

Ou

```
http://localhost:53710/Categorias/Index
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando acessar algo não é acessível, o código da *view*.

Note que na pasta **Views** existe um arquivo *web.config*, ele é o responsável por bloquear isto.

O correto é acessar **Controller/Action**, considerando que o *controller* seja `HomeController` e a action seja `Index`, o endereço seria:

> `http://localhost:53710/Home/Index`

---

Considerando a imagem postada, você deve acessar (se existir uma action `Index` no *controller*)

> ```
> http://localhost:53710/Categorias/Index
> ```